# swift playground - location of the default user file directory

Tags: ios, swift, file, directory

I cannot find a question directly related to my issue.
I've written some code in an iOS Playground that writes text to a file. The path is found by this code:

if let dir : NSString = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory, NSSearchPathDomainMask.AllDomainsMask, true).first { ...

The path that is returned is :
"/var/folders/5t/d6xvw5j54m19yfgp3ghcysd00000gp/T/com.apple.dt.Xcode.pg/containers/com.apple.dt.playground.stub.iOS_Simulator.TEST-36ED1F82-C96B-4200-8D97-42581098A517/Documents"

What is the significance of this path?

When I move my code to an iOS app, will the path be a location that I can use for user files to be stored, when the app is on a device?

Comment: The significance of this path is that playground and iOS apps are sandboxed.

Comment: You can access that path using the finder if you are using a simulator or through code if your app it is running in a real device

Comment: Leo, Thanks. I had guessed it would be due to sandboxing. I am able to see the file by pasting the path into Finder, Go, Go to Folder. When I am running this code in an app, if I leave the path as currently coded, will my app be able to read and write files, when loaded on a device?